# There are no items for you to review on a >90K queue?

Tags: discussion, review

> There are no items for you to review, matching the filter "[vba]
>   [excel-vba]"

I know all I have been reviewing lately have had a filter on it but I didn't expect to run out after a few days of reviewing :O The last questions I was reviewing were about 2 years old.

Where does that >90K come from then? (*which tags?*)

I'd rather maintain the good quality of my reviews and avoid other tags which I am not too familiar with so I do not necessarily want to jump into other tags.

Any suggestions what I can do for *the rest of the day?* <=sarcasm

How difficult is it to review other tags in terms of audits?

Comment: Filter on 'Too broad' and 'Primarily opinion based'; most of those are easy to recognize.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: For all we know those were added to the queue in the last 5 minutes.

Comment: There are 400 pages of VBA questions compared to 10282 pages of java questions. I could believe you making a major dent into the VBA queue

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd oh funny the 1st already got my vote, the second is not reviewable but Ive seen it already, and third got my comment visible :P

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd and are you saying that the *operator* for the tags is `AND` and not `OR`?

Comment: @mehow oops! My mistake, assumed it's AND by three items only. After some more reloads, it's OR.

Comment: I just review "off topic", all tags - I skip plenty and just VTC those that clearly aren't appropriate for [so], getting a pretty decent number of reviews / minute (and a more fluent interface would surely raise that number quite a bit).

Comment: @Dukeling so very true - in unfamiliar tags, generous skipping is the way to go fast and easy. Not to mention that it easily flies over audits - as long as one skips any post that doesn't firmly click at first glance, troublesome audits just go away unnoticed

Comment: TIL that you can filter the review queue!

Comment: @MartijnPieters you can post this your comment as an answer Id be happy to accept it. Just reviewed a few with those filters and it seems that I can mostly be able to judge what is either too broad or primarily opinion based. If unsure I am just skipping

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you run out of posts to review for your chosen tags, then I'd filter on 'Too broad' and 'Primarily opinion based'.

Most questions already flagged for those reasons are very easy to recognize as close candidates. Skip any that are unclear to you, but those two reasons should easily exhaust your daily review votes for weeks on end.

Answer (score 0):

Start by removing the tags that you have and see what comes up. In cases where you are unfamiliar with the subject matter and don't want to make a judgement you can just press 'skip'. After you do that for a bunch of posts, you get an idea about which tags don't have enough reviews.

Comment: The tags you enter are 'OR'ed together, not 'AND'. Removing tags won't broaden the search unless you remove the tags altogether.

Comment: Remove the tags altogether. You can latter add them again.

Comment: Of course, but your answer implies that you want the OP to remove *one* tag at a time.